# Largest value with conditions using Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I'm currently using google sheets as a publicly viewable, stats tracking document for an esports league. We have a proprietary formula that calculates something called a "role rating" which gives a hard number that allows players in a specific role to compare their level of play to another player. I wanted to display the top 5 role rating scores for each role and then use the index function to spit out the name so that whenever I upload new stats the list would automatically update with the top 5 players. So that's the backstory and here is the issue:

[Formula used and displayed error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dj2os.png)

[Tab with stats and columns I'm referencing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZexQ.png)

Now if I'm not mistaken, the formula has to be an array formula and it correctly just says "Find the largest value in D:D if the value in B:B says "top"." Is there something simple I am missing?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Query()` function will give you best result in this case. Try below query formula. You may need to adjust formula for other columns for your sheet.

```
=QUERY(B2:D,"Select D where B='Top' Order by D Desc Limit 5")
```

`FILTER()` function will also work like-

```
=SORTN(FILTER(D2:D20,B2:B20="Top"),5,,1,FALSE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your data starting on row 2, and you would like to display the result starting from `row 2` also, your calculation display error because the order of the `Large` function, then you might use the following formula to correct it, accept if helping :)

```
=large(ARRAYFORMULA(IF(B:B="Top",D:D,"")),row(F2)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! The ordering of operations may have helped but I have found that Sheets was just not accepting "Top" as an input because it stopped reading after " for whatever reason. I made a workaround by just converting the role names to integer values. Cumbersome, but it fixed the issue. Regardless, thank you for the help!

Comment: I see, accept the answer if it is helpful :)